# Coffeescript - inherit parent class from different coffeescript file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript, spine.js

I am creating a spine-rails application and have 2 coffeescript files in lib folder. I wanted to inherit a parent class in another coffeescript file but unable to do so.

```
#= require coffeescript_file_1
```

Above statement finds the target coffeescript file but cannot find the parent class.

I found this utlity:
https://github.com/fairfieldt/coffeescript-concat

Just wanted to know if using it would be the correct way to find a parent class in a  coffeescript file inside another file in a rails app.

I'm not using npm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to "export" the class. CoffeeScript uses an IIFE wrapper to avoid polluting the scope.

in your application.js :

```
#= require coffee_parent
#= require coffee_child
```

in your coffee_parent.js.coffee :

```
@Parent = class Parent
  doStuff: ->
```

in your coffee_child.js.coffee :

```
@Child = class Child extends @Parent
  doStuff: -> super 1
```